# Histograms: "TypeError, list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, list, histogram, typeerror, indices

I am trying to make a function that will take a character and a histogram and add an instance of that character to the histogram. My code so far is like this:

```
def add_to_hist(character, histogram):
    """Takes a character and a histogram and adds an occurrence
       of that character to the histogram.

    string, list -> list"""
    for c in character:
        if c not in histogram:
            histogram[c] = 1
        else:
            histogram[c] = histogram[c]+1
    return histogram
```

Every time I try to run the code it returns with `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`. Can anyone help me figure this out? My code actually might be entirely wrong, I'm very new at this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add the definition of what `histogram` is? The problem seems to be that `histogram` is a `list`, and `c` is a character. You're trying to do `[1, 2, 3]['a']`, which is not allowed (to index a list you need an integer, not a character). Maybe you want `histogram` to be a `dict` instead? That's why I think it'd be nice seeing how `histogram` is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is because you are trying to assign a key to a `list`, and `list` only can be indexed by intenger `list[0]`, `list[1]`, so on. So, `hinstogram` must be a `dict` not a `list`

Make sure when you call `add_to_hist` method, pass a dict. 
You can init a dict in that way:

```
histogram = {}
```

**UPDATED**

Based on your comment, you can't pass `[['B',1],['a',3],['n',2],['!',1]]` as param to `add_to_his`, because that is not a dict. It should be `{'B':1,'a':3,'n':2,'!':1}`

Comment: That gets rid of the Error but if I run the program with say add_to_hist('a', [['B',1],['a',3],['n',2],['!',1]] ) it only returns {'a': 1} rather than adding it to the histogram and returning the whole thing?

Comment: I mean  `[['B',1],['a',3],['n',2],['!',1]]` this is not a dict, you need to pass a dict to `add_to_his`, it should be like this `{'B':1,'a':3,'n':2,'!':1}`

Comment: @lilbanili you can check as correct answer, clicking over check mark above.